# Ambiguity in CActiveForm ajax validation

Tags: php, yii

In the [API Doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm) example for CActiveForm is:

**To respond to the AJAX validation requests, we need the following class code:**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new User;
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect('index');
    }

    $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model));
}

protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='user-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```

My question: what says this code: `$_POST['ajax']==='user-form'`? I changed it to `$_POST['ajax']==='xxxzzz'` but script worked truly! It's necessary?

---

## Edit

**My code was wrong.**

The `if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='xxx-zzz')` expression work truly. Reason of still validation performed was, in next lines i had performed the validation this way:

```
$model = new User;
$this->performAjaxValidation($model,'xxx-zzz'); //here don't perform Ajax validation
.
.
.
    if(!$validate){
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model,'user-form'); // here Ajax validation will performed
.
.
.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

$_POST['ajax'] holds the id of the form submitted for ajax validation. Take from that what you want.

As you in the documentation for `CActiveForm::validate()` it loads the model from POST-data, and $_POST['ajax'] is never used, so you could probably remove it if you want to.

It's good to make sure you don't ajax validate a form you didn't intend to validate though.

Comment: I wondering why the `if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='xxx-zzz')` evaluated to **true**? we have not a form with `xxx-zzz` **id**!

Comment: **my above knowledge was mistake, described in Edit.**

Comment: @msoa Is the problem solved now or what? I don't understand nothing.

Comment: Yes, solved, described in question edit. in same block of code i have snippet code that validation was performed.